# Is $\sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(A^2)} = \lambda_{\max}(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to prove a statement on the condition number of a matrix in the 2-norm for a symmetric positive definite matrix $A$. I nearly have the proof completed, if $\sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(A^2)} = \lambda_{\max}(A)$ then the proof is finished. But I'm not sure if this is the case? Is $\sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(A^2)} = \lambda_{\max}(A)$ for a symmetric positive definite matrix?

Comment: Hint: What is the relationship between the eigenvalues of $A$ and those of $A^2$?

Comment: The eigenvalues of $A^2$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ squared.

Comment: That's right. So if $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\mu^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$. Further, $\mu$ is real and positive so we can safely say that $\sqrt{\mu^2}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Yes thats fine thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a  symmetric positive definite matrix $A$, singular values and eigenvalues are identical.

So, $\sqrt{\lambda_{max}(A^2)}=\lambda_{max}(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be any square matrix and $(\lambda,v)$ such that $Av = \lambda v$. 
Then, $A^2v = \lambda Av = \lambda^2 v$ and so $\lambda_{\max}(A^2)= \lambda_{\max}(A)^2$.

So, if $\lambda_{\max}(A)\geq 0$ we are done, i.e. $\sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(A^2)}= \lambda_{\max}(A)$.

This is clearly the case when $A$ is positive semi-definite.
It is also the case if $A$ has nonnegative entries (by the Perron-Frobenius theorem).